# R get time difference with lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

Here is a column from one of my data frames

```
7/1/2016 2:53
7/1/2016 20:56
7/2/2016 20:58
7/2/2016 21:57
```

I've been using lubridate and its pretty good, but I was wondering if there's a way to 1) remove the date so that I just have the time so its like this

```
2:53
20:56
20:58
21:57
```

And then also get the difference from a certain time, say 8:10 pm or 20:10 so its like this

```
 -18:17
0:46
 0:48
1:47
```

And then be able to get the hour or minute value by it self.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the column to a proper datetime first.
Reformat the datetime to add the specified time back to the base date.
Take the difference.

```
dat$newdate <- as.POSIXct(dat$V1, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
dat$newdate - as.POSIXct(format(dat$newdate, "%F 20:10"))
#Time differences in mins
#[1] -1037    46    48   107
```

Where the data was:

```
dat  <- read.csv(text="7/1/2016 2:53
7/1/2016 20:56
7/2/2016 20:58
7/2/2016 21:57", header=FALSE)
```

Comment: how do I do this with lubridate?

Comment: @Shah - no idea, I have never used it.

Comment: should I post another question asking for how to do it with lubridate?

Comment: @Shah - nope, someone else may come along to help you shortly.

Answer (score 1):

With lubridate:

```
library("lubridate")

dat1 <- dmy_hm("7/1/2016 2:53")
dat2 <- dmy_hm("7/1/2016 8:09")
```

to extract hour:min just:

```
strftime(dat1, format="%H:%M:%S", tz= "UTC")
```

to get the hour and minute use:

```
hour(dat1)
minute(dat1)
```

operation example:

```
dat2-dat1
```